# Quadratic Form with perpendicular vectors

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, quadratic-forms

I have a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ with normalized gradient $\widehat{\nabla f(x)}$ and Hessian $H(x)$ at the point $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. I also know that $\widehat{y}$ is a unit vector perpendicular to the unit gradient $\widehat{y}\perp\widehat{\nabla f(x)}$. Can I say anything interesting about the following quadratic form?
$$
\widehat{\nabla f(x)}^\top H(x) \widehat{y}
$$
There is so much structure in this problem that there must be something special about this, perhaps a bound (assuming more things) or a nice expression.

Comment: How is this a quadratic form? What precisely is fixed and what is varying?

Comment: @TedShifrin That is a good point I guess, I don't know much about quadratic forms. I guess I see the above the same way as $x^\top A x$ but in this case we use two different vectors (which happen to be normalized) and the matrix $A$ is related to the first vector

Comment: So, fixing $x$, this is a linear function of $y$ (restricting to the unit sphere). Varying $x$, this is a very complicated function.